# Electron-log is causing electron app to reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-react

I am using the electron-todo template and trying to create a log file that recovers the data in the event of a crash. The app reloads every time the log file is updated. How would I prevent the app from reloading every time? I intended the logging to occur in the background while the app keeps running. In the renderer I have the following:

I cannot see any console error output upon app reload, but the log file does record as it should.

Comment: Can you share some part of the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.